# Use Crystal report in an integration flow in SAP CPI

Tags: crystal-reports, integration, service-layer, sap-cpi

I'm seeking guidance on utilizing the Crystal Reports tool within my integration flow in SAP CPI. The objective is to transmit the relevant client data and retrieve the invoice PDF generated by Crystal Reports.

I found out from this video that I can call Crystal Reports using a POST request. I post data, and then I receive a Base64-encoded response that I have to convert into a PDF.

link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l-8H9n9FrmI&t=2s&ab_channel=SAPBusinessOne

Utilizing the Crystal Reports tool within my integration flow in SAP CPI